# ReactJS - create a separate file for functions that dispatch actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

The goal here is to reduce the amount of code in my component, which looks like this:

```
import {
  increaseProductQuantity as increaseProductQuantityAction,
  decreaseProductQuantity as decreaseProductQuantityAction,
} from '~/store/modules/createCampaign/actions'

export default function MyComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  function increaseSurveyQuantity() {
    dispatch(increaseProductQuantityAction('survey'))
  }

  function decreaseSurveyQuantity() {
    dispatch(decreaseProductQuantityAction('survey'))
  }

  function increaseRewardQuantity() {
    dispatch(increaseProductQuantityAction('reward'))
  }

  function decreaseRewardQuantity() {
    dispatch(decreaseProductQuantityAction('reward'))
  }
}
```

**I've tried creating a separate file just for the functions who dispatch an action, like this:**

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

import {
  increaseProductQuantity as increaseProductQuantityAction,
  decreaseProductQuantity as decreaseProductQuantityAction,
} from '~/store/modules/createCampaign/actions'

const dispatch = useDispatch()

export function increaseSurveyQuantity() {
  dispatch(increaseProductQuantityAction('survey'))
}

export function decreaseSurveyQuantity() {
  dispatch(decreaseProductQuantityAction('survey'))
}

export function increaseRewardQuantity() {
  dispatch(increaseProductQuantityAction('reward'))
}

export function decreaseRewardQuantity() {
  dispatch(decreaseProductQuantityAction('reward'))
}
```

**In my component I've tried to import the function from the file above:**

```
import { increaseSurveyQuantity } from '~/helper/sponsorFunctions'
```

**But I was getting this error:**

`Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`.

What is the proper way to make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only use a hook inside a component or another hook. You can create a custom hook `useSurvey`, that will generate the functions, and return them:

```
import { useMemo } from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

import {
  increaseProductQuantity as increaseProductQuantityAction,
  decreaseProductQuantity as decreaseProductQuantityAction,
} from '~/store/modules/createCampaign/actions'

const useSurvey = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const actions = useMemo(() => ({
    increaseSurveyQuantity() {
      dispatch(increaseProductQuantityAction('survey'))
    },

    decreaseSurveyQuantity() {
      dispatch(decreaseProductQuantityAction('survey'))
    },

    function increaseRewardQuantity() {
      dispatch(increaseProductQuantityAction('reward'))
    },

    decreaseRewardQuantity() {
      dispatch(decreaseProductQuantityAction('reward'))
    }
  }), [dispatch])

  return actions
}

export default useSurvey
```

And you can use them in your component like this:

```
import useSurvey from '~/helper/useSurvey'

export default function MyComponent() {
  const {
    increaseSurveyQuantity,
    decreaseSurveyQuantity,
    increaseRewardQuantity,
    decreaseRewardQuantity
  } = useSurvey()

  return (
    // JSX
  );
}
```

Comment: hey @Ori thanks for the reply. But after implementing your aswer, I'm getting `Cannot read property 'increaseSurveyQuantity' of undefined` in my component. Also, in your answer, should all functions start with `function`?

Comment: Stupid mistake. The useMemo returns an object and I forgot the parentheses around it. Try now.

Comment: Hey @Ori, what if, in the same file, I need to export something like that: `const something = useSelector(state => state.something)`, I've tried but didn't work

Comment: You can return an object with actions and selected values - something like `return { actions, something }`, which you can destructure in the component.